# How to Change Package Directory in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am attempting to install a package (sldnfdraw) in SWI-Prolog, but I cannot find a way to specify an installation directory (ie where I want it to be installed).

The [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=prologpack) seems to indicate one can choose the package directory, but I haven't had luck in doing so. Admittedly, I am fairly new to Prolog and may be overlooking something obvious. Nonetheless, I have searched for answers in all the usual places (Stack Overflow, documentation) with no luck.

I attempted to install the package `sldnfdraw` by calling `pack_install(sldnfdraw).` This would have created a directory at `$HOME/lib/swipl/pack`. I then attempted various incarnations of `pack_install(sldnfdraw, $PREF_DIR).` where `$PREF_DIR` is the absolute path of the directory where I wanted the package to be installed. The documentation referenced some way of passing options to functions, but it did not specify a method for doing so. Given the limited resources available on Prolog (and this specific implementation) I find myself at a dead end. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Of interest: library [prolog_pack](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=prologpack): A package manager for Prolog

Comment: Another trick is this: download the package in whatever folder you want and then create a symlink to the default package directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for specifying the installation directory is `package_directory/1`. In order to use this in conjunction with `pack_install/2`, I needed to enclose it in brackets. Therefore the query to install package `sldnfdraw` into directory `$PREF_DIR` looks like

```
pack_install(sldfndraw, [package_directory($PREF_DIR)]).
```